# Saving authentication in cookie

Tags: apache, curl

I have enabled basic authentication on my web server and would like to only have the user enter his password once a day. After the first successful login I can save the authentication in a cookie. 
Q1. How do I make this work?
Q2. Is this the best security option? (the site is not exposed to internet)

I would like to access the site using libcurl so I am testing using curl.

Here is what I have tried:
Install and config
Download httpd binaries and uncompress in c:\install\apache24

Set the server home in httpd.conf

```
Define SRVROOT "c:/install/Apache24"
```

Generate a passwords file and place it in in c:\install\apache24\passwd
httpasswd -c passwords las

.htaccess in htdocs

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
# (Following line optional)
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile "C:/install/Apache24/passwd/passwords"
Require user bob
```

Change to all in httpd.conf

```
DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Place this index.html in

```
<header><title>This is title</title></header>
<body>
Hello world
</body>
</html>
```

Test it
On my machine by parse localhost in the proxy server
Environment variable no_proxy is set to

```
no_proxy=localhost
```

In the browser load localhost, and it will ask for a password.

In curl load using 
curl localhost -u bob:password
Or to ignore proxy without changing the environment variable
curl --noproxy "*" http://localhost

Save the authentication in a cookie and use it next time
curl -X POST -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt -u bob:password { http://localhost } -O > output.txt

curl -X POST -b cookies.txt -c cookies.txt { http://localhost } -O > output2.txt

in file output I have:

```
<html>
<header><title>This is title</title></header>
<body>
Hello world
</body>
</html>
```

In file output2.txt I have

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Unauthorized</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
</body></html>
```

Also there is no cookies.txt files

I might be doing something silly and are happy to lean!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using HTTP authentication in Apache, you can't use a cookie to bypass this.  The browser will keep the credentials as long as they don't close it.  HTTP authentication credentials are sent in the headers and cookies have no effect on whether or not it is enforced or required.

Also note that with AuthType Basic, the passwords are only base64 encoded so if your site does not use HTTPS, the passwords are easily intercepted and not at all secure.  Since you said it's not connected to the internet, this may be okay.  Still though, using [mod_auth_digest](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_digest.html) would be better.